# Can't add 1 file to object

Tags: trigger, files, contentdocumentlink

I have the requirement to create a validation rule that only allow you to set the status in closed won if a file is attached to the opportunity. To achieve this, I have created a custom field which is a counter and a custom trigger on ContentDocumentLink object which update that counter. I have tested it in my sandbox and works great but when I go in production and I try to add the file to the opportunity I get the error: Can't add 1 file to Opportunity.

I found this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381870&type=1 where it says that the error is caused because of the custom trigger, and that is true because if I disable the trigger I can add files again.

I don't understand why in the sandbox works well and not in production, I don't know what I am missing. Any idea?

Due we can't create flows on CDL object and my trigger doesn't want to work, any other idea to achieve my requirement?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you go through the other things mentioned on that post? E.g. checking the required field on Content Version object?

Comment: Yes I do, in fact I have no custom fields on Content Version object

Comment: Ok, and no validation rules either, and sufficient file storage available? There must be another difference between the orgs then. But hard to tell exactly what/where..

Comment: Yes, there is no validation rules on Content Version and the storage is in 1%... I will continue my research...

Comment: I finally solved that. I deactivated the CDL trigger in the sandbox and upload in production via changeset to deactivate that trigger in production, and then I activate the trigger in production via workbench deploy and magically I was able to attach files to the opportunity. I keep the Clairbois answer as best because is the best technical solution to my problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's hard to tell exactly what is causing this (probably a difference between the environments), an alternative could be to build the entire logic into your Opportunity Trigger.

I.e. before update (to Closed Won) do a query on `ContentDocumentLink` having that Opportunity as parent id. If the query returns anything, do an `addError()` on the Opportunity in the trigger.

Maybe this is even better practice, because it doesn't require any DML and only requires 1 SOQL query at the time of closing the opportunity.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with this approach for now because I don't know what might be different between the environments that makes the trigger not work in CDL and I can't find much more info about it.